# Comet-like with images

Tags: php, ajax, json, comet

Good evening,

I'm doing an HTTP request through AJAX to my server which returns a JSON object with the properly information and at (more or less) 10 seconds later it generates an image and returns it.
Is it possible to work with the JSON object while it waits for the image or do I have to do two diferente requests? Is there another alternative like Comet?

Thaks in advance.

Comment: If it is all during one request, to get the object before the image I believe you would need 2 requests.

Comment: That was my alternative but I was trying to find if there was a better solution. Thanks.